# Citations of images used in an app

Tags: python

I'm using the following code in order to cite the images used in my android apps. My main concern is to **never** accidentally present an image as if it were mine, while it's not.

### Questions:

1. The images I created are separately stored from third parties' images. The code in `ignore_build_ensure_images_cited.py` is run every time `main.py` is executed during development. The name intentionally contains `"ignore_build"` in order to ignore it when building the [apk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_(file_format)), since it's only needed for developing. **Should I be doing this a different way**, that is, by not ignoring the file?
2. I tend to name files, variables, classes etc in a perhaps strange way. For example instead of using "third_part**y**_images" I use "third_part**ies**_images", in order to indicate that the dir is related to multiple parties and their images. If it were "part**y**" that would indicate the dir is related to a single party with multiple images. (asking in general about relevant coding practices, not specifically about this post's code)

- Is there a better way to express such info through naming?
- Is there any downside to using such a naming convention?

3. What else could I do in order to make it even more reliable in terms of not forgetting to attribute, and attributing *correctly* (e.g. not forgetting to set `adaptation=True` if I've modified the image)?

---

### Directory tree

- project_dir

  - main.py
  - third_parties_images
  - own_images
  - citations.py
  - ignore_build_ensure_images_cited.py

---

### main.py

(this is just the bottom of the file)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        import ignore_build_ensure_images_cited
    except ImportError:
        pass

    MinusTimesMinusApp().run()
```

---

### ignore_build_ensure_images_cited.py

```
import os
import citations

INCLUDED_IMAGES = set(os.listdir('third_parties_images'))
CITED_IMAGES = citations.IMAGES_CITED
FILES_NOT_CITED = INCLUDED_IMAGES - CITED_IMAGES
if INCLUDED_IMAGES - CITED_IMAGES:
    raise NotImplementedError('Following image files were not cited: {}'.format(FILES_NOT_CITED))

REDUNDANT_CITATIONS = CITED_IMAGES - INCLUDED_IMAGES
if REDUNDANT_CITATIONS:
    print('Found citations without their corresponding image: {}'.format(REDUNDANT_CITATIONS))
```

---

### citations.py

```
"""Used for citing all third party images.
An image could have several derivatives.
In that case all its derivatives have the same citation.
"""
ACCEPTABLE_LICENSES = {'cc0', 'public domain', 'cc by'}

IMAGES_CITED = set()    # File names
FIRST_IMAGE_TO_CITATION_MAP = {}


class ImageCitation(object):
    """
    Used for citing each individual work.
    Citation includes all related data along with extra requirements by the copyright owner.
    NOTE: Assumes the returned text will be displayed with markup enabled.
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 work_name,
                 creation_date,
                 licence,
                 adaptation,
                 file_names,
                 creator_name=None, creator_pseudonym=None,
                 url='',
                 extra_text='',
                 ignore=False):
        """
        Takes all needed data for the citation.
        Creator can be identified by either name or pseudonym.
        In case of a pseudonym, pseudonym related origin should be present.
        WARNING: In case of multiple files, start with original file
            since only the first image is displayed.
        :param work_name: (str)
        :param creator_name: (str)
        :param creator_pseudonym: (str) Pseudonym with pseudonym origin, e.g. "TallPony (wikipedia user)"
        :param creation_date: (str) Work creation date. e.g. 10-May-2015 (avoid displaying month as a number)
        :param url: (str)
        :param licence: (str) "cc0", "public domain" etc
        :param adaptation: (bool) Adapted (modified) or original work (refers to first file in file_names)
        :param file_names: (list) Names of all image files derived from the work.
        :param extra_text: (str) Extra text required by the copyright owner.
        :param ignore: (bool) Used if citation has been created but image is not included.
            Useful in case a previously discarded image is used again, in order to avoid creating 
            its citation all over again.
        """
        if not (creator_name or creator_pseudonym):
            raise ValueError('At least one of `creator_name` and `creator_pseudonym` should be provided.')
        if creator_name and creator_pseudonym:
            raise ValueError('Only one of `creator_name` and `creator_pseudonym` should be provided.')
        if licence not in ACCEPTABLE_LICENSES:
            raise ValueError('Licence not acceptable')

        self.file_names = file_names
        self.adaptation = adaptation
        self.licence = licence
        self.url = url
        self.creation_date = creation_date
        self.creator_name = creator_name
        self.creator_pseudonym = creator_pseudonym
        self._creator = creator_name or creator_pseudonym
        self.work_name = work_name
        self.extra_text = extra_text

        if not ignore:
            IMAGES_CITED.update(file_names)
            FIRST_IMAGE_TO_CITATION_MAP.update({file_names[0]: self})

    def full_text(self):
        """
        Final citation text.
        NOTE: Assumes markup is done by "[b]", "[size=8]", etc.
        """
        final_text = ("[b]{work_name}[/b] image by {creator} ({creation_date}). "
                      "\n[size=10]{url}[/size]").format(work_name=self.work_name,
                                                        creator=self._creator,
                                                        creation_date=self.creation_date,
                                                        url=self.url)

        if self.adaptation:
            final_text = 'My adaptation of ' + final_text

        if self.extra_text:
            final_text += '\n' + self.extra_text

        return '[size=12]{}[/size]'.format(final_text)


# (To be used for copy-pasting when creating new ImageCitation
# in order to avoid accidentally forgetting to change an arg value.)
"""
 = ImageCitation(
    work_name=,
    creation_date=,
    licence=,
    adaptation=,
    file_names=,
    creator_name=,
    creator_pseudonym=,
    url=,
    extra_text=)
"""

GOLD_ZEUS_COIN = ImageCitation(
    work_name='Zeus with a laurel crown, gold stater from Lampsacus',
    creation_date='2010',
    licence='public domain',
    adaptation=True,
    file_names=['gold_coin_zeus_small.png'],
    creator_name=None,
    creator_pseudonym='Jastrow (wikipedia user)',
    url='commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stater_Zeus_Lampsacus_CdM.jpg',
    extra_text='')

TICK_YES = ImageCitation(
    work_name='check',
    creation_date='Oct 18, 2013',
    licence='public domain',
    adaptation=False,
    file_names=['tick_yes.png', 'tick_no.png'],
    creator_name=None,
    creator_pseudonym='OpenClipart-Vectors (pixabay user)',
    url='https://pixabay.com/en/check-correct-green-mark-tick-157822/',
    extra_text='')

GOLD_LAUREL = ImageCitation(
    work_name='Golden laurel wreath',
    creation_date='April 2007',
    licence='public domain',
    adaptation=False,
    file_names=['gold_laurel_small.jpg', ],
    creator_name=None,
    creator_pseudonym='Andreas Praefcke (wikipedia user)',
    url='https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lorbeerkranz_Zypern_rem.jpg',
    extra_text='Golden laurel wreath, probably from Cyprus, 4th/3rd century BC; Reiss-Engelhorn-Museen, Mannheim, Germany')

SILVER_COIN = ImageCitation(
    work_name='Silver Tetradrachm of Athens 454-415 BC',
    creation_date='23 November 2010',
    licence='cc0',
    adaptation=False,
    file_names=['athena_coin.png', 'athena_coin_small.png'],
    creator_name=None,
    creator_pseudonym='yuichi (wikipedia user)',
    url='https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Athens_owl_coin.jpg',
    extra_text='')


NAVAGIO = ImageCitation(
    work_name='zakhyntos shipwreck',
    creation_date='Sept. 11, 2011',
    licence='public domain',
    adaptation=True,
    file_names=['navagio_adapt.png'],
    creator_name=None,
    creator_pseudonym='ytora (pixabay user)',
    url='https://pixabay.com/en/zakhyntos-zakintosz-shipwreck-1432220/',
    extra_text
    ='')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print()
    print(GOLD_ZEUS_COIN.full_text())
```

Comment: I don't think you can use "third parties" like that, but that's a question better suited for http://english.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better way to express such info through naming?

Make it grammatically correct, so just say `third_party_images`. Maintaining "ies" would require an apostrophe, which isn't possible in variable names. Making the conjugation goofy as an internal convention is not helpful. Any additional information can be added in your documentation - docstrings or otherwise.

> Is there any downside to using such a naming convention?

Yes. The convention isn't obvious to someone new to your project, so doesn't convey any additional information, and it's grammatically incorrect, which makes people sad.

Other than that,

### Type hints

Your convention to add `(str)` in the docstring instead of `:str` on the parameter is good if you're trapped in Python 2. But if you're at all able to use Python 3 (the tags don't specify), just use type hints.

Past that, your docstrings are missing descriptions for some parameters.

### Concatenation or formatting?

Your approach in `full_text` is fine. You may also choose to avoid concatenation by setting up snippet variables that are unconditionally added to the format string, so that there only needs to be one `format` call; something like

```
adaptation = 'My adaptation of ' if self.adaptation else ''
extra_text = f'\n{self.extra_text}' if self.extra_text else ''

final_text = (
    '[size=12]'
    f'{adaptation}[b]{self.work_name}[/b] '
    f'image by {self._creator} '
    f'({self.creation_date}). \n'
    f'[size=10]{self.url}[/size]'
    f'{extra_text}[/size]'
)
```

### Mandatory args

> To be used for copy-pasting when creating new ImageCitation
>   in order to avoid accidentally forgetting to change an arg value.

I can see where you're coming from, but if this is actually a problem, consider making more (or all) arguments mandatory. It's fairly unusual to leave around boilerplate code for the express purpose of copy-and-paste, and the requirement for such a thing means that perhaps

- you're not using a Python editor/IDE with good static analysis and autocomplete, and/or
- your method's parameters are not strict enough in requiring that values be passed.

All of that said, you shouldn't have to be passing `creator_name=None` so many times; that's the default. Just leave it out. The same goes for `extra_text`. That's the whole point of default arguments.